# Referencing multiple models with Passport.js with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, passport.js

So I have successfully implemented a user authentication using Passport.js.
Right now I am trying to implement a random URL generator for resetting passwords/confirming accounts/etc.  But I cannot seem to reference the database table through Sequelize.

*How do I reference an already-defined model in Sequelize outside the module it was defined in?*

In the code below `user` is passed via `function(passport, user)`.  Adding a third parameter to its call in server.js (e.g. `require('./app/config/passport.js')(passport, data.user, data.hashedURL)` ) does not fix the problem.

Below is what I think are the relevant portions.  I can post more if need be.  Error point is indicated by an arrow in `passport.js` module below.
Thanks so much in advance for any light you can shed!

server.js

```
var express       = require('express'),
    expHandlebars = require('express-handlebars'),
    session       = require('express-session'),
    cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser'),
    bodyParser    = require('body-parser'),

    app           = express(),
    fs            = require('fs'),
    path          = require('path'),
    passport      = require('passport'),
    flash         = require('connect-flash');

var passport = require('passport');
var env = require('dotenv').config();

app.engine('handlebars', hbs = require('express-handlebars')
    .create({
        extname:        '.handlebars', 
        defaultLayout:  'main',
        layoutsDir:     path.join(__dirname, '/views/layouts/'),
        partialsDir:    path.join(__dirname, 'views/partials/')
    }).engine
);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));    

//bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 
    extended: true 
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//passport
app.use(session(
        { 
            secret:           'ahahawouldntyouliketoknow?', 
            cookie: {
                maxAge:        259200,  //30 days
                secure:        false
            },
            resave:            true,
            saveUninitialized: true
})); 

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());// session secret
app.use(flash());

//Models
var data = require('./app/data/');

//Routes
var authRoute = require('./app/routes/auth.js')(app, passport);

//load passport strategies
require('./app/config/passport.js')(passport, data.user);

app.listen(5000, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Site is live");
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

/app/routes/auth.js

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {  
    app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        res.render('home', {
            page_title: "Seeing is Believing",
            inc_style: true,
            style_sheet: "style/home.css",
        });
    });

    //Routing for 'forgot password' functionality
    app.get('/forgot', function(req, res) {
        console.log("!" + req.flash('error'));
        res.send();
    });

    app.post('/forgot', passport.authenticate('user-forgot-password', {
        successRedirect: '/forgot',
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash: true
    }));

    ...

};
```

/app/config/passport.js

```
var bCrypt          = require('bcrypt-nodejs'),
    LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    CustomStrategy  = require('passport-custom').Strategy,
    Sequelize       = require('sequelize'),
    verify          = require('./verify');

module.exports = function(passport, user) {
    var User = user;
    var Hashed_URL = Sequelize.models("HashedURL");

    console.log(Hashed_URL);

    // Serialize User
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    // Deserialize User 
    passport.deserializeUser(function(user_id, done) {
        User.findByPk(user_id).then(function(user) {
            if (user) {
                done(null, user.get());
            } else {
                done(user.errors, null);
            }
        });
    });

    //
    function makeURL(length) {
        var result           = '';
        var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        var charactersLength = characters.length;

        for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
            for ( var j = 0; j < 5; j++ ) {
                result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength)) + '-';
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    //
    var generateHash = function(password) {
        return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
    };

    //Forgot password
    passport.use('user-forgot-password', new CustomStrategy(function(req, done) {
        console.log("0");
        User.findOne({
                where: { 
                    'login_key':    req.body.user_email
                }
        }).then(function(user) {
            console.log("1");
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { 
                    message: "Unable to find username \'".concat(login_key).concat("\'.")
                });
            }

            var randomURL = makeURL(39);
            var data = {
                    hashed_url:         randomURL,
                    uid:                user.id,
                    email_info:         "",
                    email_contents:     "<h1>I LEIK PUGS</h1>",
                    attempts:           1
            };

            Hashed_URL.create(data).then(function(newURL, created) {    <--- this is where the error occurs
                if (!newURL) {
                    return done(null, false);
                }

                if (newURL) {
                    return done(null, newUser);
                }
            });

            return done(null, user);
        });
    }));

...
```

};

/app/data/user.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
    var User = sequelize.define('user', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },

        ...

    });

    return User;
};
```

/app/data/hashedURL.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
    var hashed_URL = sequelize.define('HashedURL', {
        expiration_time: {
            type: 'TIMESTAMP',
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
            primaryKey: true
        },

        ...

    });

    return hashed_URL;
};
```

/app/data/index.js

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
var config = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'config', 'config.json'))[env];
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
var db = {};

fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(function(file) {
        return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
    })
    .forEach(function(file) {
        var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
    if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: try db.models[modelName] or db[modelName]. You're exporting db from /app/data/index.js, so you can grab it from there

Comment: This was it!  Thanks a million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [i.brod's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8340889/i-brod) comment I was able to solve the problem.

This is what I have right now:

auth.js

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {  
    app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        res.render('home', {
            page_title: "Seeing is Believing",
            inc_style: true,
            style_sheet: "style/home.css",
        });
    });

    //Routing for 'forgot password' functionality
    app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.flash('error'));
        res.send();
    });

    app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('user-login-email', {
        successRedirect: '/dashboard',
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash: true
    }));

    app.get('/reset/?code=:hash', function(req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('user-reset-password', {
            successRedirect: res.render('inside', { 
                                page_title: "Change Your Password",
                                portal: function() {
                                    return "reset";
                                }
                            }),
            failureRedirect: '/',
            failureFlash: true
        })(req, res, next);
    });

    app.post('/reset', function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.flash('error'));
        res.send();
    });

    ...

};
```

passport.js

```
module.exports = function(passport, user) {
    var User = user;
    var Hashed_URL = db["hashed_url"];

    passport.serializeUser((obj, done) => {
          if (obj instanceof User) {
              done(null, { id: obj.id, type: 'User' });
          } else {
              done(null, { id: obj.id, type: 'Hashed_URL' });
          }
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
        if (obj.type === 'User') {
            User.findByPk(obj.id).then((user) => done(null, user));
        } else {
            Hashed_URL.findByPk(obj.id).then((hashedURL) => done(null, hashedURL));
        }
    });

    //
    function makeURL(length) {
        var result           = '';
        var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        var charactersLength = characters.length;

        for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
            for ( var j = 0; j < 8; j++ ) {
                result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
            }

            if (i < (length - 1)) {
                result += '-';
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    //
    var generateHash = function(password) {
        return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
    };

    // Forgot password (send email)
    passport.use('user-forgot-password', new CustomStrategy(function(req, done) {
        User.findOne({
                where: { 
                    'login_key':    req.body.user_email
                }
        }).then(function(user) {
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { 
                    message: "Unable to find username \'".concat(login_key).concat("\'.")
                });
            }

            var randomURL = 'f' + makeURL(26);
            var data = {
                    hashed_url:         randomURL,
                    id:                 user.id,
                    email_info:         "{'to':'sam.neal@verizon.net'}",
                    email_contents:     "<h1>I LEIK PUGS</h1>",
                    attempts:           1
            };

            Hashed_URL.create(data).then(function(newURL, created) {
                if (!newURL) {
                    console.log("A");
                    return done(null, false);
                }

                if (newURL) {
                    console.log("B");
                    return done(null, newURL);
                }
            });
        });
    }));

    ...

};
```

I do not think I altered anything else.
Note: the random URL generator was just for testing, I think [JWT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback) or hashing would be more ideal for generating temporary secure URLs.

I'll try to post as much of the final program as I can on my [git](https://github.com/snealbli/user-authenticate) when it is complete.